# snapshot returns always empty data in StreamBuilder flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot, stream-builder

So, I'm facing this problem: the '**snapshot**' doesn't get any data from Firestore in **StreamBuilder** in Flutter.$

Here is the code:

```
StreamBuilder<Driver>(
  initialData: null,
  stream: DatabaseServices(uid: driver.uid).driverData,
  builder: (streamContext, snapshot) {
    print(driver.uid);
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      Driver currentDriver = snapshot.data;
      print(currentDriver.fullName);
      print(currentDriver.email);
    } else {
      print('no data');
    }
  }
)
```

**Note:** `stream: DatabaseServices(uid: driver.uid).driverData`
-> **driver** here works fine on top of the whole code and gets the driver data such as uid.

And this code always returns '**no data**'.

The weird thing here is that I'm using the **same code** (with another kind of user -> **Client**) in another screen, and **it works normally**, and it **gets the data properly**.

And in Firestore, I have 2 collections, **Driver** and **Clients**, almost the same attributes.

It even has a **SubCollection** for both collections and it called '**Notification**', and I'm using a **StreamBuilder** to show the notifications for both **Client** and **Driver** and **it works normally**.

Comment: If you're using the same code somewhere else and it works as intended, it sounds like the problem comes from the context (what is above the widget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, the problem was in some attribute that I called it with the wrong name that used in the other collection (Client), I forgot to change it.